# Positioning iFrame?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a google maps frame on my website in a specific location. I can get the iframe to go where I want, but as soon as I put it on another monitor or browser the location changes.

Anyone know how to position this iframe to specific location and not change depending on browser/monitor size?

Code:

```
<div id="contentframe" style="position: absolute;overflow:hidden;right:20%;top:70%; height:50%;width:50%">
```

CodePen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzInu

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Use a fixed unit instead of percentages? Used fixed positioning?

Comment: Remove the absolute positioning.

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you to the guy who posted and then deleted his answer. Your answer worked! If anyone needs a solution: I made the accordion: <div id="accordion-container" style="position:relative;"> and made the iframe absolute.  <div id="contentframe" style="float:right; position:absolute; left:65%; top:40%;">